# Kill python script after driver is closed ? (Selenium, python)

Tags: python, selenium, driver, exit

Kill python script after driver is closed ? (Selenium, python)
So if the user closed the chrome driver, the script closes too.
That's really all, have been searching on google for a while and haven't found anything. Thank you in advance

Comment: you are explaingin something or asking how to do it ?

Comment: I'm asking, sorry if I didn't explain well enough. Not native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
       
    browser.implicitly_wait(10)
    browser.get(url)
    #more code

except Exception as e:

    if "not reachable" in str(e):
        print("Chrome crashed :" + str(e))
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Some Other Exception was thrown: " + str(e))
        raise Exception(str(e))
```

Just catch the exception and use sys.exit()

THis will exit script gracefully for chrome close , for all other it will throw that exception

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a bit of code to help us, but chrome driver is close by the script anyway, assuming you are using Selenium for tests you can use the [TearDown method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown) for exemple :

```
def tearDownClass(cls):
        super().tearDownClass()
        cls.browser.quit()
```